Изменить код ответа с 307 на 301 при перенаправлении на https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

Не понимаю, когда открываю страницу с http, переадресовывает с кодом 307 вместо 301.
Как это можно поправить?

Этот вопрос похож на: Заставить переадресацию делать с 301 кодом, вместо 307. Если вы считаете его другим, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чётко обозначив отличие и/или почему ответы на вопрос не помогли в вашем случае.

Не задавайте один и тот же вопрос несколько раз. Если нужно дополнить вопрос - отредактируйте его.
